# Help creating zip files with 50 files in each

Tags: finder, automator, script, zip

I have a folder containing 7.000 images that needs to be zipped into zip files containing only 50 files each.

Any way of doing this automatically? Any script, Automator workflow, batch whatever would be helpful.

I am not very experienced in using either, so please be specific.

I am running OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty BASH script.

Assumptions: All of your photos are in a folder, and there's nothing else in this folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
zip_count=0
files_zipped=0
folder_number=1
div=50
numfiles=(*)
numfiles=${#numfiles[@]}

mkdir zips

for file in *
do

  file_list="$file_list \"$file\""
  let "zip_count=zip_count+1"
  let "files_zipped=files_zipped+1"

  if [ "$files_zipped" -eq "$numfiles" ]; then
    echo "Final ZIP..."
    echo $file_list | xargs zip -9 zips/$folder_number.zip
  fi

  if [ "$zip_count" -eq "$div" ]; then
    echo "Next Zip..."
    echo $file_list | xargs zip zips/$folder_number.zip
    let "folder_number=folder_number+1"
    zip_count=0
    file_list=""
  fi

done
```

You can download it [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12899811/zip50.sh?dl=1)

Once you've downloaded it:

1. Open Terminal.app and change to the directory with your photos in it e.g. `cd /path/to/photos`
2. Run the commmand `bash ~/Downloads/zip50.sh` (assuming you've downloaded the script to your downloads folder.)
3. A new folder called "zips" will be created in the folder with your photos.

Comment: I tested your script and it appears to work, although you might want to run your script through [http://www.shellcheck.net/](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and see if any of the warnings are worth addressing.